# XCode 4.2: Deleted Resources still referenced in project (red filenames)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to remove the MGTwitter library in favor of the iOS 5 Twitter Framework. However, when I went to remove the library it's still being referenced when I *Build* and causing a failure.

[image]

I've tried:

- Removing resources by *Reference Only*
- Removing resources by *Delete*
- Removing resources by deleting in *Finder*
- *Clean*ing the project
- Restarting XCode
- Restarting machine

Can't seem to get these references to go away. Is there a way to simply *refresh* the project resources?

Comment: did you check the dependencies in your project?

Comment: I wonder why those source files have the turn down arrow on them. That is normally reserved for folder or files that can be localized.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your app's Target, under the **Build Phases** tab.

Removing any red files from the **Compile Sources** section should resolve your problem.

[image]

Comment: None of the files in red are listed under this section. Damn, I was hopeful :)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary do you have multiple targets? They need to be removed for every target.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and the red classes that were renamed were above the project icon. I chose Show Package Contents of the .xcodeproj in finder. Then I chose Show Package Contents of project.xcworkspace. Used TextEdit to open contents.xcworkspacedata which gave an XML file. I deleted from **FileRef** to **/FileRef** of the offending red file. Xcode prompted me to use updated version and of course I said yes.

I tried all other approaches before stumbling on this. Hope this does the trick.

BTW FileRef has a < and a > that I couldn't add to the above answer. Erase those too.